# Fibonacci sequence python without the term zero

Tags: python

Just wondering if there was any possible way to print out a fibonacci sequence starting with **1**.
**Example:**

Fibonacci sequence for MAX = 17 is as
1,
1,
2,
3,
5,
8,
13,
21,
34,
55,
89,
144,
233,
377,
610,
987.

This is the current code I have:

```
MAX = 17
n1, n2 = 0,1
i= 0
while i < MAX:
    print(n1)
    nth = n1 + n2
    n1 = n2
    n2 = nth
    i +=1
```

I don't know how to get rid of zero without hindering the code.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of 0? You can't change the output without changing the code, but you can *filter* the output once it is produced. How you do that depends on how you executing your code, but it is independent of the code itself: it happens *outside* the Python script.

Comment: If you think the Fibonacci numbers should start with 1, then there's no reason to set `n1 = 0` in the first place. If you think the Fibonacci numbers *should* start with 0, there's no reason to skip 0 in the output.

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions to the recurrence F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2). What picks one over any of the others are the initial conditions in the form of your definitions for `F(0)` and `F(1)` (or `F(1)` and `F(2)`, if you don't consider n=0 the starting point).

Answer (score 1):

To perform this action, I would do the following:

I would start n1 and n2 at 1 and 1, respectively. Like this:

```
MAX = 17
n1, n2 = 1, 1
i = 0
while i < MAX:
  print(n1)
  nth = n1 + n2
  n1 = n2
  n2 = nth
  i += 1
```

I think you can also get the same result by changing the "`while`" loop to `i<= MAX` and making "`MAX`" start at 16.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Another way to do it is to keep the `0, 1` and move the `print(n1)` after assigning to the variables. Either way works.

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
try using a for loop

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 0
fb = 0
for i in range(17):
    if (fb > 0):
        print(fb)
    fb = n1 + n2
    n1 = n2 
    n2 = fb
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the result as you want. All I have done here is, set `i=1` instead `i=0`. Also, I am printing **n2** instead of **n1** using `print(n2)`.

```
MAX = 17
n1, n2 = 0,1
i= 1
while i < MAX:
    print(n2)
    nth = n1 + n2
    n1 = n2
    n2 = nth
    i +=1
```

Answer (score -1):

try setting i = 1 at line 3

```
MAX = 17
n1, n2 = 0,1
i= 0
while i < MAX:
    print(n1)
    nth = n1 + n2
    n1 = n2
    n2 = nth
    i +=1
```

Comment: That would still start with 0, but emit one *fewer* Fibonacci number.